# Building access controls removed for leavers

Tags: resignation, employer-relations, termination

My workplace recently updated the access control system so now you need to swipe in and out and if the system thinks you're inside already, it won't let you come in again (say you forgot to swipe out and simply followed someone else out).

My question relates to something that I overheard one of the managers talking about a couple of times (I think they are probably just joking), but they implied that they could stop someone in the office from being able to sign out if they had just resigned or were going to be fired to stop them leaving the building until after management had spoken to them.  I don't think they would actually do that, but if they did would this be an acceptable business practice?  To the knowledge of the people here would this even be legal?

The doors open automatically in the event of a fire alarm.  We are based in the UK.

Thanks.

Comment: Keeping someone in the building against their will could probably lead to criminal charges. If you tried to hold me, it would lead to a 999 call (and preventing me from calling the police would most definitely lead to criminal charges) and the police arriving. So I suppose it's not an acceptable business practice.

Comment: This is verging into legal territory and therefore off-topic, but that sounds like [false imprisonment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trespass_in_English_law#False_imprisonment). IANAL.

Comment: That was my thinking as well (hence why I'm assuming that this is supposed to be a joke from an otherwise sensible manager, but it got me thinking).

Comment: http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/a/2694

Comment: @gnat, you think that this is an issue that cannot happen anywhere else?

Comment: If the building/company has security people, I would think that they could detain someone 'under suspicion' just as they do at stores for shoplifters.

Comment: @mkennedy Detaining me 'under suspicion' of shoplifting is one thing. Detaining me 'under suspicion' of nothing would lead me straight to court with a complaint of false imprisonment. They take me anywhere I don't want to go, and I'll add a complaint of kidnapping.

Comment: @VietnhiPhuvan Oh, I agree, but I thought it worth pointing out. I think most companies can get most, if not all, employees on 'misuse of computer equipment' or something similar though.

Comment: @mkennedy only a very few employers would have that quasi legal ability and even fewer would exercise that right and especially not for trivial reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in the comments, fire doors should never be locked against egress, though there may sometimes be a brief delay before opening (typically 30 seconds). Note "should" -- violations do sometimes occur, but that can get a company in a mega-buttload of trouble in any country that actively enforces fire codes.

There *are* some security systems where, short of that kind of emergency, employees are supposed to badge out as well as badge in. Pulling the badge before they've left could be a nuisance. On the other hand, that would be assumed to be an error, and Security should treat it as a lost badge and deal appropriately.

So, yeah, this is almost certainly a joke. Or a misunderstanding. (I *have* seen a situation where someone was fired on the spot, had their badge confiscated, and were escorted off the property. I would presume that if they weren't already on the property, the badge would have been cancelled from the permissions list just as quickly. But that's a different question.)